# WPF Animate transform set by style

Tags: wpf, animation, transform

I've made a custom WPF control that periodically replaces elements in its Children collection. The control inherits from Grid, to allow proper stretching of the child elements.

There are two DependencyProperties (and corresponding properties) of type FrameworkElement: `CurrentElement` and `NextElement`. Each time a DispatcherTimer ticks, the CurrentElement is replaced with the NextElement, and the NextElement is assigned a new element which is added to the Children collection. It also raises an event, in which I want to animate the two elements to get a nice transition.

EDIT: I've edited my question, the initial problem I had with the animation not doing anything was caused by something else in my implementation. I am having another problem now though.

My animation XAML looks like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="CurrentElement.RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                 From="0" To="-1000" Duration="0:0:1" />
```

That works fine as long as I define the RenderTransform on the element itself. But, I would ideally like to set the RenderTransform in a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}" x:Key="Gallery.Item">
   <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
      <Setter.Value>
         <TranslateTransform X="0" />
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

This results in an exception as soon as the animation starts:

> 'RenderTransform' property value in the path
>   'CurrentElement.RenderTransform.(0)' points to immutable instance of
>   'System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform'.

Comment: Try this: `Storyboard.Target="CurrentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"`.

Comment: `Storyboard.Target="CurrentElement"` throws an exception: "'CurrentElement' is not a valid value for property 'Target'."